# Force all ImportHTML functions across multiple sheets in a document to refresh periodically

Tags: google-sheets

I need to have the import HTML function automatically update on every sheet.

No idea how to do this.

Here is a copy of the spread sheet.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qbpM8GOHVrdhglZ7BvJ7m-nZ2Juw6hVGVMM0lpbzE_8/edit?usp=sharing

As is described I need the existing importhtml functions to periodically update automatically.

Comment: Hi, did you ever work how to do this? I need it for a sheet I'm constructing. Thanks, Henry

Answer (score 1):

you can try choosing it in settings:

[image]

Comment: Sadly, this affects only how often NOW, TODAY, RAND, and RANDBETWEEN are updated.